# Websockets connection failing only with Chrome accessing ASP Core Server using subprotocol

Tags: c#, google-chrome, websocket, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a MQTT client / broker implementation, client is browser websockets based, server is ASPNetCore 1.1 with Kestrel & Websockets (0.1.0).

As part of the MQTT spec, I am initiating a websockets connection using "MQTT" as the subprotocol, which the Server looks for when establishing the websockets connection.

JavaScript connection established using the following:

```
var wsMQTT = new WebSocket(g.protocol + "//" + g.serverName + ":" + net.WSPORT, "MQTT");
wsMQTT.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```

Here is the Chrome error (basically timeout as nothing coming back from the server):

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received.
```

Here is the ASPNetCore middleware for handling the websocket connection:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            CancellationToken ct = context.RequestAborted;
            WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

            MQTT.Broker MQTTClient = new MQTT.Broker(_host, webSocket, context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(), context.Connection.RemotePort.ToString(), _MQTTUser, _MQTTPass);
            MQTTClient.TimeoutEvent += CloseWSSess;                                         // When MQTT stack sees ping/resp timeout, shut down WS

            if (context.WebSockets.WebSocketRequestedProtocols.Count == 1 &&
context.WebSockets.WebSocketRequestedProtocols[0].Substring(0, 4) == "MQTT")
            {
                _host.WriteLog(LOGTYPES.INFORMATION, "Received new MQTT WebSocket connection from " + context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);

                // receive loop
                while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested && webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    var response = await ReceiveBin(MQTTClient, ct);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CloseWSSess(MQTTClient, "Invalid WebSockets subprotocol requested from client [" + context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() + "]. Session aborted.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);                // Not a web socket request
        }
    }
```

Here is the error stack from ASP Core (which isn't getting trapped inside the websockets library):

```
Connection id "0HL5GB806MGNU": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of stream at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol.CommonWebSocket.<EnsureDataAvailableOrReadAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
```

Works fine with IE, Edge and Firefox, and doesn't crash ASP Core if I remove the subprotocol from the client connection. So I suspect Chrome is establishing the connection a little differently to the other browsers which isn't being handled properly by ASP Core Websockets.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is to specify the subprotocol in AcceptWebSocketAsync (ie. AcceptWebSocketAsync("MQTT").